# How to serve gRPC and gRPC-web on single port?

Tags: flutter, dart, backend, grpc, grpc-web

I have a multi-platform app that uses gRPC for front-back end communication.

Long story long:
App usage scenario

```
          backend             transport        various clients

[             gRPC(Server) ] -- gRPC -- [ flutter app + bloc + gRPC ] 
[ gRPC + Postgres backend  ]
[    gRPC-web(HttpServer?) ] -- gRPCw -- [ flutter web + bloc + gRPC-web ]
```

All connections happen on the same port.

- application works fine, uses defined services and interacts with database
- I do get http connection data on backend separately, so no issues on transfer part

The question is: How to consume that grpc-web connection on server side?
I got to the point of

```dart
 final webServer = await HttpServer.bind(
    '0.0.0.0',
    rpcPort,
    shared: true,
  );
  print(' gRPC-web port ${webServer.port}');

  await for (HttpRequest request in webServer) {

    print(request);
  }
```

it gets connection(`Instance of '_HttpRequest'`), but how do I "feed" it to `services`?

update 1: gRPC server code, I'm looking for similar with gRPC-web

```dart
final server = Server.create(
    services: [
      SiteMethodsService(databaseCore),
      CategoryMethodsService(databaseCore)
    ],
    interceptors: [],
    codecRegistry: CodecRegistry(codecs: const [GzipCodec(), IdentityCodec()]),
  );
```

Comment: Rather than the raw HttpServer you should probably use `shelf` and then you can use `shelf_router` to push requests around. See https://pub.dev/packages/shelf/example Shelf also gives you useful utilities like request logging with middleware, which are also useful to add CORS headers as needed. Finally, use `shelf_static` when you eventually want to serve your Flutter web app.

Comment: That's a bit confusing, gRPC and gRPC-web are different [protocols](https://pub.dev/documentation/grpc/latest/grpc_or_grpcweb/GrpcOrGrpcWebClientChannel-class.html) now I can make channel on client side and `dart-grpc` allows me to: `<see update 1 in initial quesion>`
I wonder why there is no such method for gRPC web? It seems strange that I need to write it by hand or I just cant find it.

Comment: Is you server also written in Dart? Do you use Envoy proxy?

Comment: Server is written in `dart` (`shelf` as http server) right now it's simply interface between gRPC and PostgreSQL database with `drift` framework.
If possible I would like to avoid adding third software solutions to pipeline. Given right headers, dart can decode http request by itself.
I get request url like: `/backend.site.SiteMethods/SitesReadAll` and data. All I need now is correct way to use this data with `class Site extends $pb.GeneratedMessage`, i.e. parse url and deserialize data if any. Should be possible with native gRPC tools or could be written. I wonder if such feature exists.

Comment: `Envoy` proxy is a bit excessive in my opinion. I'm trying to make web application as fast as possible. Also there should be a good reason to use additional container with proxy. Right now I'm thinking how `ServerHandler` class here `https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/blob/master/lib/src/server/handler.dart` can be modified to serve gRPC-web connections.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I'm wondering the exact same thing. I don't really want to spin up a full docker proxy server for my small project, and I feel like the grpc dart server should be able to handle grpc-web requests just like it does for regular grpc requests.

Comment: There is no such functionality.
Answered here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/issues/685
I'll try to write and push it to repo.
Right now I plan to handle per request answers. Original implementation handles stream. If there are architecture suggestions, now it's the time.